# php webhook is not a valid process webhook job class. A valid class should implement `Spatie\WebhookClient\ProcessWebhookJob`

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks

I got this error when receiving webhook
I'm trying to solve it, I found the error in storage/logs.

error
production.ERROR: `app\Handler\WebhookHandler` is not a valid process webhook job class. A valid class should implement `Spatie\WebhookClient\ProcessWebhookJob`.

Config:
webhook-client.php

```
<?php

return [
    'configs' => [
        [
            'name' => 'default',
            'signing_secret' => env('CLIENT_SECRET'),
            'signature_header_name' => 'Signature', \Spatie\WebhookClient\SignatureValidator\SignatureValidator
             */
            'signature_validator' => \Spatie\WebhookClient\SignatureValidator\DefaultSignatureValidator::class,
            'webhook_profile' => \Spatie\WebhookClient\WebhookProfile\ProcessEverythingWebhookProfile::class,
            'webhook_response' => \Spatie\WebhookClient\WebhookResponse\DefaultRespondsTo::class,
            'webhook_model' => \Spatie\WebhookClient\Models\WebhookCall::class,
            'process_webhook_job' => app\Handler\WebhookHandler::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Class:
WebhookHandler.php

```
<?php

namespace app\Handler;

use Spatie\WebhookClient\ProcessWebhookJob;

class WebhookHandler extends ProcessWebhookJob
{

    public function handle()
    {
        error_log('test');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be \App\Handler\WebhookHandler::class. Due to composer autoloading, it is in the namespace of `App` instead of the folder structure `app`. Similar your namespace in the Webhook should be `namespace App\Handler;`.

Instead the more safe solution is to write WebhookHandler::class and let your IDE or similar autoinclude it as an use statement.

```
use App\Handler\WebhookHandler;

...

'process_webhook_job' => WebhookHandler::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

For laravel 9 and above
Instead of :

```
Spatie\WebhookClient\ProcessWebhookJob
```

Use :

```
Spatie\WebhookClient\Jobs\ProcessWebhookJob
```